# How to run SQL queries after this in Hackerrank? What does it mean?

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, runtime-error

ERROR 1044 (4200) at line 5:Access Denied for user '@'localhost to database 'company'

Comment: Please include the code that's giving you that error.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar problem. You need to log in as a user with permissions. Sometimes you can also be logged in as an anonymous user. So then you will need to check which user you are logged in as and what permissions you have.
If you can provide your code that will help even further.